# Difference between map.keySet().contains() and map.containsKey()

Tags: java

Is there any difference between these two statements when I just want to set an 'if' statement?

```
// it is a HashMap

if (map.keySet().contains(myKey)) { //do something...}

if (map.containsKey(myKey)){ //do the same thing...}
```

Comment: It makes very little speed difference, although as [Arturo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32173684/2071828) points out there may be some. The main disadvantage of the first line is that it's _confusing_ - other developers will wonder **why** you have used a non-standard construct.

Answer (score 17):

`containsKey()` is faster. `keySet()` returns a set backed by the HashMap itself, and its `contains()` method calls `containsKey()`.

This is its implementation:

```
public final boolean contains(Object o) { return containsKey(o); }
```

(http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#913)

Comment: I suppose `containsKey` may be faster, but when the only difference is a single extra layer of indirection via a simple method call, that performance difference is going to be beyond trivial.

Comment: @AlexisKing unless the `keySet` needs to be constructed; which it will be the first time this method is called...

Comment: @BoristheSpider True, but that allocation will be tiny since `KeySet` is a non-static inner class, so no actual initialization will need to be done.